# Refactoring repeated expressions in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following PostgreSQL query:

```sql
SELECT extract(YEAR from date), AVG(amount) 
FROM transactions 
GROUP BY extract(YEAR from date) 
ORDER BY extract(YEAR from date)
```

How can I refactor the query so that `extract(YEAR from date)` does not have to be repeated in the query?

Comment: They aren't repeated expressions but they *do* point to a bug - you can't use any indexes that cover `date` if you group and order on a function result. If the table has no Year column, the common solution is to use a Calendar table (a table with precalculated dates and extra reporting/grouping columns for the next eg 20 years), join on the date and group, order by the calendar table's year or month columns

Comment: You could rewrite the query using a CTE or inner query so `extract(YEAR from date)` only appeared once, but the performance bug would remain

Comment: Won't postgresql let you group by the alias?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Why would it be a bug? Just create an index on the year and you suddenly have an index on this year: `CREATE INDEX idx_year ON transactions (extract(YEAR from date));`. The only issue is, that you need a large range of years to make it a useful one. Maybe it could be useful when you also include the amount, to avoid the table lookup.

Comment: @FrankHeikens you did have to explicitly create that index. `extract(YEAR from date)` would prevent any index on `date` and force a full table scan. Given the answers, there will be a lot of scans

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If you want to, you could create two indexes. But given the fact that there is a limit number of years, I would first see if an index on just the year makes any sense. Most likely it does when you include the amount as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is more readable or not, but you can refer to the output column ID:

```
SELECT extract(YEAR from date), AVG(amount) 
FROM transactions 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: FWIW I *always* use column numbers for group by and order by.

Comment: This is definitely the most concise way to write it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can use a common table expression.

```sql
WITH year_avg AS (
  SELECT extract(YEAR from date) AS transaction_year, AVG(amount) AS avg_amount
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY transaction_year
)
```

This will create a CTE for you and then you can later, call it using

```sql
SELECT transaction_year, avg_amount
FROM year_avg
ORDER BY transaction_year;
```

The main query selects the results from the CTE and orders them by `transaction_year`, doing this, you don't need to repeat the extract(YEAR from date) expression in the main query and the `year_avg` CTE calculates the average amount for each year by extracting the year from the date column and grouping it.

Comment: This is not as concise as the answer by @JGH. However, this is the one that I was looking for, but didn't know how to write. Thank you for including the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using subquery as follows :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT extract(YEAR from date) as year, AVG(amount) AS avg_amount
  FROM transactions 
  GROUP BY extract(YEAR from date)
)
ORDER BY year;
```